# I can't select UWP ListView items in codedui

Tags: uwp, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have a UWP application and I'm using CodedUI for UWP

It contains a report which is created as a ListView, and I need to verify some values in this list. But when I try to use the cross hair tool to drag it on the row or the list, the application keeps hanging, and when I succeeded in capturing the row then I ran the test case it failed because Codedui  couldn't find the control.

In the attached photo I can capture Home tab button and other tabs and the drop downs and the buttons below it only, but If I drag the cross hair tool on the list it keeps hanging the application until I close it

[image]

what visualstudio captured for the listitem row
[image]

After running getchildren for the main window and then getparents hierarchy for the listitem control this is how they look like 
[image]

Comment: Can you find control that you want in the UI Control Map?

Comment: Hi Memok,
Did you try selecting a row with the cross hair when there were less listview Items? The thing is, UITestControl object have parent-children relationships. Meaning a parent control (your listview) can have many children (the listview items). I have this theory that when you use your cross hair on a listview item vs has to sift trough all those children to find the listview item you want to select. having less listview items could possibly speed things up. Can you verify that for me pls?

Comment: About not finding the control. Did you make sure your listview was loaded completely before your test tried to access one of its children? You can use functions like `UITestControl.WaitForControlExist()` for these purposes.

Comment: @Milan When I try to use the crosshair tool to highlight the row (1 out of 10 attempts succeeds otherwise it hangs ) I find it in the UI Control Map with path (UIWindow.UIItemCustom.UIItemList.UIItem201807052049SECTListItem).
UIItem201807052049SECTListItem is the row id and it's a dynamic ID So I tried to debug to check if the parent UIItemList.exist is true and use GetChildren() but I found it false.

Comment: Hi @PixelPlex , Yes I tried selecting with just 2 rows in the list and still same behaviour it hangs whenever I drag the crosshair across a cell. 
And as I mentioned in the previous comment when I was lucky to capture the row I tried the parent and grand parent.exist and I added Playback.Wait(4000); to be sure it was loaded without even waits failure problems.
The report is done by xaml StackLayout->Grid->Listview->Grid

Comment: memok, continuing on the answer you gave to @Milan. You mentioned the rows have a dynamic ID. Does that mean the ID's of the listviewItems will be different every time you load that listview? If that is the case, did you check if that dynamic ID is used in the searchproperties of the generated code when the control gets added to the UIMap (using the cross hear and pressing ctrl+shift+ I)? Running your test would result in  a control not found exception because that ID stored in the searchproperties of that control would not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I possibly have a alternative to your problem. Below code will take a parent control and sift trough it until all children are added in a recursive way, respecting the control hierarchy. That way, you will have all available listview items at runtime. Control not found exceptions shouldn't be a issue here if you keep the KeyValuePair up-to-date whenever the listview item collection changes.

Use this recursive method:

```
    public ParentControl GetChildControls(UITestControl parentControl)
    {
        ParentControl parent = new ParentControl();

        if (parentControl != null)
        {
            List<ParentControl> children = new List<ParentControl>();

            foreach (UITestControl childControl in parentControl.GetChildren())
            {
                children.Add(GetChildControls(childControl));
            }

            parent.Children = new KeyValuePair<UITestControl, List<ParentControl>>(parentControl, children);
        }

        return parent;
    }
```

The ParentControl object:

```
public class ParentControl
{
    public KeyValuePair<UITestControl, List<ParentControl>> Children { get; set; }
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return Children.Key.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

The Children property is mandatory , other properties are optional.

Comment: There is something I don't get it. If the row list hierarchy is "UIWindow.UIItemCustom.UIItemList.UIItem201807052049SECTListItem"
and I will use getchildren function and pass the UIWindow like this
"UIFMELogWindow window=GetChildControls(this.UIMap.UIFMELogWindow); "
then how will I access the children list?

Comment: The recursive method adds all childern in a list of key-value pairs. The key is the parent, the value are the children. So if you provide UIItemCustom as a parameter to this recursive method, you will receive a Key-Value pair containing that UIItemCustom as key. The value will be a list of key-value pairs where the keys are the UIItemCustom children and the values being a new list ofkey-value pairs containing the grandchildren, and so on...

Just try the code and dissect the object you get back from it in the watch, it might make it easier to understand.

Comment: In your case it would be more efficient to provide the listview as a parameter instead of the whole window so the function does not need to dig that deep.
To get to the children, try searching google on how to do a recursive iteration. You could for example check if key object type is a list Item and add it to another list with a flat structure.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm new to codedui so It's taking me a while to implement things. I made getchildren and I printed the the control.name and control.controlType.name. It made the structure a bit clearer. when I passed UIWindow but when I try to pass UIItemCustom the control is not found. I tried to make an if condition when it founds a cell with some value to go and getparent but it fails. I'm totally lost now

Comment: When I succeed in getting the hierarchy I should use it to make classes for these controls like what present in the designer right ?

Comment: You can use the `UITestControl.ControlType` property on the KeyValuePair key, to check against the ControlType property.
E.g.:
`parent ParentControl = GetChildren();

if (parent.Key.ControlType == ControlType.ListItem)
{
   //your logic here
}
else
{
   //other logic here
}`
No need to make extra classes. Every UITestControl has a underlaying controlType.

Comment: You can also cast your UITestControl to the appropriate Control type.
I'll use WPFList in my example:  
`WpfList list = (WpfList)parent.Children.Key:`  
or use the WpfList constructor overload:  
`WpfList list = new WpfList(parent.Children.Key);`

Comment: So we will use getchildren() whenever we want to access the control right ? but I don't have a proper parent for the listitems except the main window which gets all the application.. please check the main post I will add some photos for clarification

Comment: Viewing the second image, I see your UIItemList and its children, those list items. If you can view it in the Coded UI Test Builder, you should be able to add it to your UIMap. If you add one of those 3 listItems with ctrl+shift+I, the parent should be added to your UIMap too. Than us that UIItemList as parameter for the GetChildControls, it should return all available listItems.

Comment: Viewing the third image, you should be able to drill down to your ListItems and their properties. I'm guessing your object at index 1 will contain those items. It's possible you will get errors running through those properties while debugging, but all properties should be available at runtime.  I don't really see any problems with the screenshots you provided.

Comment: Did you see this article? It's a bit old though.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tapas_sahoos_blog/2011/01/28/accessing-some-unreachable-wpf-controls-in-coded-ui-test/

Comment: I got it working at last !!! Thanks a million my problem was getchildren got me a different hierarchy than the ui test builder produced. This was confusing me alot. Thanks alot, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your welcome memok. This community has helped me so much in the past, I felt it was time to give something back :-)

Comment: Yes this community is awesome about that. I Wish I could get experienced enough to help others like you oneday .. keep going :)